# i need to render text, but not in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've looked quite a lot but can't find a good text rendering solution. In my case uiwebview doesn't fullfil my needs. Also the text has to be with multiple fonts. I would like it to be like in iBooks, the text renders very fast(not like in the uiwebview) or maybe it's uiwebview, but then how do they do it to load that fast?

The text should also support text selection and other user interactions.

I'm open for suggestions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML), it creates `NSAttributedString` from HTML, and at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) (or [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)), a drop-in replacement for `UILabel` that supports `NSAttributedStrings`.

Comment: i read somewhere that this is suitable when one has control of the html doc, i don't have it. And to write a parser for it will took to much time. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should look at [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html).  It is framework intended specifically for text rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the Core Text framework. It can be a bit complicated to use just for some lines of text, but it may be what you are looking for.

Here is the Apple official documentation :
[Core Text Framework Apple official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH3-SW1)

And here is a good link for beginners :
[Befriending Core Text](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/)

Comment: In my case i need text selection, also another user interaction, so i guess that doesn't fit my needs, yes?

Comment: Nope. I didn't see that in your question, sorry ;)

Comment: Too bad.. Hope that this was the solution for me.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Text selection and user interaction with CoreText is not so simple.

The best open source library that I know of that supports text selection is [OmniGroup](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup).

Look at their TextEditor example for something similar to what you requested.